# Parse multipart/form-data from Buffer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Buffer which I know is a `multipart/form-data` payload, and I also know the HTTP `Content-Type` header in advance, which includes the boundary.

There are modules such as node-formidable which work only on http request streams, so what I'm interested in is how to parse a multipart payload synchronously?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the source for `formidable`'s [`form.parse()`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/4cf6b7ee3df75023b1cc084519e12ce52a3e9a55/lib/incoming_form.js#L49-L137), you should be able to do mimic most of what it's doing internally.

Another solution might be to use something like [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) which gives you a plain old parser stream to write to, so you might end up with something like:

```
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var bb = new Busboy({ headers: { 'content-type': '....' } });

bb.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  console.log('File [%s]: filename=%j; encoding=%j; mimetype=%j',
              fieldname, filename, encoding, mimetype);
  file.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('File [%s] got %d bytes', fieldname, data.length);
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log('File [%s] Finished', fieldname);
  });
}).on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
  console.log('Field [%s]: value: %j', fieldname, val);
}).on('finish', function() {
  console.log('Done parsing form!');
});

bb.end(someBuffer);
```

Comment: Using this i get a "done parsing form" but no "fields" or "data" is parsed. I'm using a buffer provided by https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods and the POST is being sent by mailgun " Sample POST" WebHook test. any ideas?