# How to parse body params on AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, lambda

On my AWS lambda function i have access to an event json which holds a parameter called: `body`. the issue is this is a raw body string (not parsed into individual parameters).

```
{
  input: {
    body: "------WebKitFormBoundarys3wLu6HlaCBrIExe\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foo\"\r\n\r\nbar\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarys3wLu6HlaCBrIExe\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"\r\n\r\nhthtth\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarys3wLu6HlaCBrIExe\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"\r\n\r\nlololol\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarys3wLu6HlaCBrIExe--\r\n"
  }
}
```

I'd like to take that and turn into:

```
{
  foo: 'bar',
  media: [
    "grgkoerpkge",
    "twepgbopcib"
  ]
}
```

I'd prefer not to use some bloated express server just to parse a body string.

*P.S. I've tried to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) but it seems like it only works with express as a middleware*

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599028/parse-multipart-form-data-from-body-as-string-on-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

```
const {URLSearchParams} = require('url')
const sp = new URLSearchParams(event.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar issue recently, as content-type in request was plain text format, I used `querystring`, built in module in node js to parse body string,
[more about querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
```

& in lambda handler,

```
var jsonData = querystring.parse(event.body);
```

Comment: This only works when the body `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, doesn't work for `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score -1):

Send it to your lambda as JSON.

Then, in your lambda (if you use `lambda-proxy` integration), parse it by using `JSON.parse(event.body)`.

Comment: I can't control what's sent to me - it's a webhook from a service

Answer (score -1):

You'r passing the params by form or with the "Content-Type" in the header "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

You shoukd pass it with "application/json"