# AWS API gateway to pass file through lambda to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to build an API with API gateway to accept a file upload. I am going through `lambda` so that I can manipulate the file name before passing it on to S3 bucket

In the event body i can see the file contents but can't seem to access the file name.

Right now Im not implementing anything to move file to S3 because I haven't been able to access the file name.

the code is as follows

```
import sys
import os
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event,context):
eventBody = json.dumps(event['body'])

return {
'statusCode': 200,
'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
'body': eventBody,
'isBase64Encoded': False
}
```

the event body looks as follows

```
"----------------------------210938299122441198584130\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nthis is a test file\r\n----------------------------210938299122441198584130--\r\n"
```

I can see that the filename is there but I cant seem to access it.

i had been trying

```
filename = json.loads(eventBody)['filename']
```

but this does not work. is there a way to access the filename from the post request in lambda?

Comment: FYI your back-end can dictate the key of the uploaded S3 object by creating a pre-signed upload URL and sending that to the client which then uploads directly to that URL without the limitations of proxying the upload request through your Lambda function.

Comment: This may be helpful: [Parse multipart/form-data from body as string on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599028/parse-multipart-form-data-from-body-as-string-on-aws-lambda)

Comment: Using this video i found it very helpful and this implementation worked, for some reason with some other implementations i was trying there were issues. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hROwNOKQTyM

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway does not handle binary files well (at least from my experience). Assume you have this use case.

A Client app (ie - React) lets a user select and upload a photo that is placed into an S3 bucket. The client can make a request that goes through API Gateway. However- do not try to post the file to API Gateway.

The solution is from an API Gateway endpoint, invoke an S3 operation that generates a presigned URL and then returns that Presigned URL to the client app. Then the Client app uses the Presigned URL (which has a time limit) to upload the photo to the bucket. This is all explained in the link below that is located in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html).

Overview illustration:

[image]

Full Code Example:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_cross_PAM_section.html)